# is there a better way to do this than my way?

Tags: java, for-loop

I was asked the following question on a job interview. I was asked to do a form of 'padded printing' using an `*` character. Here is the code I provided as my answer (in java):

edit:

something like this: User input 3:

```
x x x x x
x * * * x
x * * * x
x * * * x 
x x x x x>


public class asterisk {

    public static void main (String args[]){
        int input,ast;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        input = scan.nextInt();


        if(input>0) {
            topBottom(input);
            for(int x=1; x<=input; x++){
                System.out.print("x ");
                for( ast=1; ast<=input; ast++) {
                    System.out.print("* ");

                }
                System.out.print("x ");
                System.out.println();
            }
            topBottom(input);
        } else {
            System.out.print("x ");
        }    
    }

    public static void topBottom(int input) {           
        for(int top = 1; top<=input+2; top++ ) {
            System.out.print("x ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

}

Is there a better more efficient way to do this aside from my way? Also, what did i do poorly in my code?

It would really mean a lot to me. I am now practicing commonly asked interview coding questions.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The goal of this exercise is not to make you code an "efficient" algorithm. It's just to see if you understand loops. Try to make it readable, to use short, well-named methods, to be consistent in your spacings, to indent the code properly. Also, loops traditionally start at 0 in Java. And variables are declared and initialized at the last moment, in the narrowest scope.

Comment: for starters: public final static String CROSS = "x "; public final static String STAR = "* ";  - then use System.print(STAR); or CROSS

Comment: @MichaelD. - if you want to enter code, please "answer" instead of commenting... Difficult to read unformatted code ..

Comment: code looks good . Make it more readable like Michael D suggested.

Comment: thanks for all of the input Well with the coding IDK if somehow it change but I just copy/pasted if from my netbeans and I think I forgot to format. Thanks @JB nizet Michaek D and TheLostMind

Comment: @JB Nizet
so if loops starts with 0 if i changed this to 0 i will change the operator <= to < right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good but a few suggestions.
By convention, methods should start with a verb. The use of the `topBottom` function is questionable. I find it makes the code more confusing than anything. Consider readability as well as efficiency.

An approach like this is easier to read and doesn't include the extra method.

For n+2 chars in n+2 rows

```
for(int i=0; i<input+2; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<input+2; j++) {
```

Always print `X` for the first and last rows

```
    if(i == 0 || i == input+1) {
      System.out.print("X ");
    }
```

For all other rows print `X` for the first and last character, otherwise print `*`

```
    else {
      if(j == 0 || j == input+1) {
        System.out.print("X ");
      } else {
        System.out.print("* ");
      }
    }
```

Final Result:

```
for(int i=0; i<input+2; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<input+2; j++) {
    if(i == 0 || i == input+1) {
      System.out.print("X ");
    } else {
      if(j == 0 || j == input+1) {
        System.out.print("X ");
      } else {
        System.out.print("* ");
      }
    }
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: hmm this looks interesting. Looks a little bit different than my answer but i see the logic I will try and study this one as well. Many thanks @Jordonias

Comment: Nice explaination. Also, you can collapse the 2 IFs into one: 
if ((i == 0 || i == input + 1) || (j == 0 || j == input + 1))

Answer (score 0):

Minor changes, @Michael code , to print next line and print the char inside inner loop

```
      //  y = column
      for(int y=0; y < input; y++){     
        //  x = row
        for(int x=0; x< input; x++){
          nextChar = (x == 0 || y == 0 || (x+1) == input 
            || (y+1) == input) ? BORDER : FILLING;
            System.out.print(nextChar);
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
```

Comment: it's possible to omit the System.out.println(); by changing the nextChar line to : nextChar = (x == 0 || y == 0) ?  BORDER : ((x+1) == input || (y+1) == input) ? BORDER."\n" : FILLING;